# How to get all emails from raw strings

Tags: python, regex, email, web, screen-scraping

I tried this code:

```
contents = 'alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com.....thankyou'
    match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', contents)
    print match
```

Result:

```
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com.....thankyou
```

I want to remove `....thankyou` from my email

Is it possible to obtain only `alok.014@gmail.yahoo.com`
and one more thing the content list is bigger so I want some changes in
`re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', contents)`
if it is possible.

Comment: Without any extra constraints, that doesn't look possible. Suppose you have `something.something@yahoo.it.was.great`. How do you tell where the address ends?

Comment: Are all the emails followed by `.....`? Is there a limited set of top level domains in the list (like .org, .com etc.)? Answering these may make your problem easier. Right now, the regex you're using, and other more sophisticated email regexes seem to regard the whole string as valid email.

Comment: no, only some emails contails ".....thanks"

Comment: Do they end always with `.com`?

Comment: no there are numbers of domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about python, but languages like Java have libraries that help validate URLs and email addresses. *Alternately, you can use a well-vetted regex expression.*

My suggestion would be to keep removing the end of the string based on dots until the string validates. So test the string, and if it doesn't validate as an email, read the string from the right until you encounter a period, then drop the period and everything to the right and start again.

So you'd loop through like this

```
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com.....thankyou
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com....
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com...
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com..
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com.
alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com
```

At which point it would validate as a real email address. Yes, it's slow. Yes, it can be tricked. But it will work most of the time based on the little info (possible strings) given.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! And, here's a `Python Regex` program to help make extraction of email from the `contents` possible:

```
import re

contents = 'alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com.....thankyou'

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
[a-zA-Z0-9.]+         # username
@                     # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.com    # domain             
''', re.VERBOSE)      # re.VERBOSE helps make Regex multi-line with comments for better readability

extractEmail = emailRegex.findall(contents)
print(extractEmail)
```

Output will be:

```
['alokm.014@gmail.yahoo.com']
```

I will now suggest that you refer to this [Regex-HowTo doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to understand what's happening in this program and to come up with a better version that could extract all the emails from your larger text.